# Play store 2020: Is there a review process for "promoting" an app from closed testing to production?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

So I just submitted an app for closed alpha testing. The release status is "being reviewed".

After this, I will need to promote the exact same app (no new updates/upgrades/APK uploads) to open testing and prod. At each stage, will there again be a separate review process?

There is an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464284/google-play-review-process-through-alpha-beta-and-production-channels) but it is a couple of years old, and it seems like the review process has changed recently. So I am asking again.

Comment: I guess they have added a review at each stage. My app is currently in the Open Testing track and it's been 12 hours since they are showing status as "Being reviewed"! I am expecting the same review time delay in my Production as well after seeing that states.

Answer (score 4):

it looks like they have indeed implemented a new review process for each of the different release tracks.

However, even though a "Being reviewed" message appears below the release, you'll notice another ["Promote release" dropdown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VkXZ.png). If you click on it, you'll have the option to promote to any other active track, even straight to Production.

To answer your question - there will be distinct review processes per release track (as you noted), but the option to instantly promote is available.

Comment: What exactly is the reason behind all these reviews, especially the Closed testing?

Comment: I just promoted to Production an already reviewed Closed Testing and got into In Review again. Makes zero sense